# Sending file and metadata in HTTP response body with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm looking to send a file from my server to a client upon a get request, along with some metadata that describes the file's contents, all in the HTTP response body. The response should also be in application/json. I understand that there is likely better ways to do this, but my client requires me to do so.

Just passing the file like this works great:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/download/{filename}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
        Resource resource;
        try {
            resource = resourceService.getResource(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(resource);
    }
```

However, when I put the metadata and the Resource object in a seperate object and create a response body out of this object, the server throws following exception when I send a HTTP request:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.BufferedInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.BufferedInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

How can I send a file through an HTTP response while also providing my metadata in the same body?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No serializer found for class using Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370430/no-serializer-found-for-class-using-json)